# how can I fix Python error: "HTTP Error 502"?

Tags: python, api, http, web-scraping

I wrote this function to call weather api

```
def weather_data(df):
    import json
    query_data = urllib.request.urlopen(f"https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/{df['Latitude']},{df['Longitude']}/{df['date_time_epoch']}?key= any key ID")
    json_decode = query_data.read().decode('utf-8')
    extracted_info = json.loads(json_decode)
    temp = extracted_info['days'][0]['temp']
    feelslike = extracted_info['days'][0]['feelslike']
    return pd.Series([temp, feelslike])
```

When I test to call 10K-35K records, There is no problem. However, when I run it to call 500K ->400K -> 200K record, it shows `HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway`. I pay the subscription fee to use this service.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: If you put the exact same URL string into a browser, what do you get?

Comment: I will get the full info as I expect. However, when I called 500K ->400K -> 200K records, it showed the error

Comment: That implies that the server has a rate limit.